# Upload multiple images to server from Android app

Tags: php, android, http, file-upload

I need to upload multiple images to PHP server from Android application. Multiple means that user can upload just 1 picture, or 2, or 3 or even 5 images.

Images I need to send to server with parameter path[numberOfImage], like this:

```
reqEntity.addPart("path[0]", bab);
```

With this code I can upload an image to server.

```
    File file1 = new File(selectedPath1);
    Bitmap bitmap = decodeFile(file1);      
    ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 75, bos);
    byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();         

    try
    {
         HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
         HttpPost post = new HttpPost(urlString);

         ByteArrayBody bab = new ByteArrayBody(data, "test.jpg");

         MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();

         reqEntity.addPart("path[0]", bab);

         post.setEntity(reqEntity);
         HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
         resEntity = response.getEntity();
         response_str = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);
     }
```

Comment: And what's the problem? Did you try putting it in a loop?

Comment: Yeha, but how I can put in loop when I need multiple files and multiple ByteArrayBody?

Comment: You'll have to upload your files one-by-one, so the server side may know what's the beggining of one file and the end of another. You just need to put the code you've written in a loop, save the images you want to send somewhere (an `Array` for instance), and make as much `HTTP POST` requests as files you have.

Comment: Can you provide some sample code and I will accept your answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply put it in a loop. Assuming you have an `array` of files (in this example called `myFiles`), you would just do something like this. Bear in mind that it's important of each iteration to create a new object of everything, so this way you're making sure you're sending always a different and independent object.

```
int i = 0;

String[] myFiles = { "C:\path1.jpg", "C:\path2.jpg" };

for (String selectedPath : myFiles) {
  File file = new File(selectedPath);
  Bitmap bitmap = decodeFile(file);
  ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
  bitmap.compress(CompressFormat.JPEG, 75, bos);
  byte[] data = bos.toByteArray();         

  try {
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(urlString);

    ByteArrayBody bab = new ByteArrayBody(data, "test.jpg");

    MultipartEntity reqEntity = new MultipartEntity();

    reqEntity.addPart("path[" + String.valueOf(i++) + "]", bab);

    post.setEntity(reqEntity);
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(post);
    resEntity = response.getEntity();
    response_str = EntityUtils.toString(resEntity);
  }
  catch (...) { ... }
}
```

Comment: I cannot test it right now, I just adapted your code to what it would be, if you still have doubts I'll have a check tonight.

Comment: i cannot be resolved to a variable, because String.valueOf(i++) isn't part of for loop.

Comment: In my example I declared `i` outside (above) the loop, and increment it in this line. It just converts the current `i` to its value and increments it, it should compile.

Comment: Hey, I need help again on this problem? Can you help me?

Comment: please will someone look here? :(

Comment: Why am I supposed to declare a specific picture as in this line "ByteArrayBody bab = new ByteArrayBody(data, "test.jpg");" if I am sending multiple pictures?

Comment: What should be the approach when upload multiple file in Amazon S3?